# Facebook graph API won't return friends work history

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let's rule out the obvious...

**My Facebook app requests the following permissions**: `user_work_history, friends_work_history`

...so the usual suspect (insufficient permissions) *isn't* the source of my problem.

**ISSUE:**

The following graph api call works perfectly: `/me/friends?fields=name,work`

I get back names, ids, work history, etc. Just like you'd expect.

**BUT**

When I replace the `/me` with the user id of one my apps users (who has already authorized the app), I can only see names and ids (no work or education fields).

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why, is the access token you are using is not the access token belonging to the user you want to look at.  Check out your token in the linter tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint) and see who it belongs to.

When you do get a user access token for that individual, then you can use it to get their friends.  You wont need to specify `/{userid}/friends?fields=name,work` (although you could), just `/me/friends?fields=name,work` since the access token belongs to that user id.

Comment: Interesting! This makes sense but I want to make sure I completely understand. I'm using the PHP SDK to make my calls to the API. I'm new to it, but I think what you're saying means I need to create new `$facebook` object for each user query. Is that right?

Comment: That's really not necessary.  When the user is logged in, the PHP SDK will automatically use an access token belonging to that person.

Comment: Right, I get that part. But remember my app needs to retrieve work history info from friends of the NON-logged in user. Those would be users that have already authorized the app, but aren't the current user. If I understand correctly, I somehow need to generate a separate access key on their behalf. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You can get an extended access token, good for 60 days, for each user to obtain information after they log out.  See http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ for some good information on making a 60 day token.   When making the query to facebook via the PHP SDK, you can add the user's extended access token to the querystring of your request so that way you can reuse the same `$facebook` object.

Comment: I read that link and it's useful. However, I'm not having any luck figuring out how to request the new longer-lasting access token with the PHP sdk. I have trouble finding things in their documentation, so maybe I'm missing it.

Comment: It's mid way down that page.  Search for `fb_exchange_token` and you will find it.  Happy coding.

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit I still can't figure it out! From what I've read, the permission `offline_access` is no longer used. So we have to generate a special access token. I'm currently doing `$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();` Is there something like `$accessToken = $facebook->getExtendedAccessToken();`?

Comment: I don't know the PHP SDK very well (I use C# and the JS SDK).  Maybe they've improved it to have a getExtendedAccessToken, maybe they haven't.  Check http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ to see what they've done.

Comment: I'm totally striking out for how to do this with the PHP SDK. I'm debating redoing it with the JS SDK. Can you point me in the right direction for how to do it with JS?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/ is the JS SDK equivalent to the PHP's $facebook->api calls.

Comment: I just re-ready your original answer form yesterday... and I think I overlooked something really important... I have to store a unique access_token for each user, don't I? I've been making all my api calls from the same access_token, which is always that of the logged in user. Therefore, non-public info from "second-degree" friends will never be accessible... because the call is sent with a 3rd party's access_token. I feel like a dunce, but am I finally getting this?

Comment: That was it! I needed to store and then use user-specific access tokens. Thanks for all your help!